# Installation and configuration of WHONIX

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, tor

I have been trying for 2 days to install, configure and run Whonix. I followed the advice of 2 tutorials found on Youtube ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahFRWC8fPMs in French and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nr1qpz8oNiY in English ) which helped me more or less but my problem at the moment is that I can't connect to Tor anymore. I also have other configuration problems (forced to use qwerty instead of azerty, update problem etc...)
Anyway, if someone is using Whonix with VirtualBox, could he explain me how to install Whonix-Gateway and Whonix-Workstation and how to configure them correctly to have an "optimal" use of Whonix.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Have a nice day!

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details, which is the starting point for helping understand and respond to support questions.

Comment: Hi!
Here is some additional information. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Whonix ( https://www.whonix.org/ ) is an operating system that can be compared to TAILS except that Whonix can be used with a virtual machine which in this case is VirtualBox. 
I use (or rather, I try to use) Whonix-XFCE-16.0.5.3
The problems I encounter are numerous and probably come from a bad configuration of Whonix...
So if someone is using Whonix, it would be really interesting to ask him some questions... ;)

Thanks a lot!